# How to install iPython on Snow Leopard

Tags: python, macos, ipython

Does iPython work on Mac OS X 10.6.1 Snow Leopard? I'm python noob, how can I install iPython on my Mac? Links? suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To install with the Apple-supplied Python in 10.6:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/easy_install-2.6 ipython
```

To use:

```
$ ipython
```

Comment: No need for the full path, just `sudo easy_install ipython`

Comment: the mac comes with easy_install built in?!?

Comment: In this case, the full path is the easy_way to ensure that the package is installed with a specific Python instance, the Apple-supplied Python, avoiding the ambiguities of the OP's $PATH setting and what other Pythons and setuptools packages have been installed.

Comment: Yes, Apple supplies an easy_install with its Python (in both 10.5 and 10.6).  A fair number of other optional packages, too.

Comment: This results in a broken ipython history: using the up and down arrows will show history in the wrong part ofthe screen. This is due to OS X using BSD readline and iPython being written for GNU readline. I'm looking for an answer myself here, but can at least confirm the answer above (and any other that do not install GNU readline) does not give a working ipython history.

Comment: The 32-bit-only Python Mac OS X installers from python.org are built with GNU readline.  You could try installing one of them, then a new easy_install (using setuptools or Distribute), and ipython.  Or you could install a complete solution from a 3rd-party distributor, like from MacPorts, which has ipython ports for py26 and py27 (and will install a new compatible Python and all dependencies).

Answer (score 8):

I may add that running

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/easy_install-2.6 readline ipython
```

gives you the ability to use tab completion to see the attributes of a module....

Comment: readline must be preinstalled on 10.6 at least, since tab completion works for me after following the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Though ipython installs and is runnable using easy_install, I found that there were some rendering problems which could only be solved by installing pyreadline as well. However, i found that there were some problems with pyreadline's installation using easy_install. The solution i've gone with involves manually extracting the python package and editing the version of gnu-readline which pyreadline tries to compile. I've posted a more in depth guide [on my blog](http://www.sinjax.net/wordpress/?p=1705)

Cheers

-- Sina

Comment: the blog is a 404, could you post another link?

Comment: Modded down for lacking an included answer, and once more if I could for 404ing.

Answer (score 0):

As with other python extensions, [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) makes it quite easy:

```
sudo pip install ipython
```