# What's the difference between using easyintall-2.6 and easy install-2.7 to install ipython

Tags: python, macos, ipython, easy-install

I install ipython on Mac OS X Lion following this:
[How to install iPython on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437402/how-to-install-ipython-on-snow-leopard)

As I doing this on my Mac
sudo /usr/bin/easy_install-2.6 python

Turns out I originally have easy_install-2.5, 2.6, 2.7 installed!

Then I choose easy_install-2.7 to install python, it works.

But what if I install ipython with 2.5, 2.6 version of easy_install?
What's going on behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will install IPython for the different versions of Python installed on the system. Starting IPython for each version will bring up a shell for the appropriate version of Python.

Comment: Thanks!I see.So easy_install is contained in installation of Python on Mac OS. If you install different version Python, you will have different version of easy_install, as in one to one relationship.