# IPython without Anaconda?

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, osx-mavericks, anaconda

I want to install IPython on a Mac running Mavericks (10.9), which comes with python 2.7 pre-installed where you expect: /usr/bin/python. The only IPython install I see online requires Anaconda, which installs *another* python 2.7.

Since I see that the Linux installation don't (seem to) involve Anaconda, I wonder if there  is a way for me to evade adding an apparently superfluous python installation. I mean, storage doesn't grow on trees...

Or should I just byte (so to speak) the bullet?

Comment: Alternative is Enthought Canopy. Same issue though.

Comment: Sure Mac OS X comes with Python, but does that Python have tornado, pyzmq, pyside, ... (all dependencies of the IPython notebook and qtconsole)? Mac OS X's system Python is just one dependency of IPython. Anaconda comes with *all* the dependencies of IPython.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want IPython in the terminal you can `pip install ipython`. If you want the notebook or the qtconsole, you can spend days trying to get all the dependencies installed (good luck with it, I outlined how I did it a long time ago at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Installing-the-IPython-qtconsole-in-Mac-OS-X, which may not be correct any more, I don't know), or you can just install Anaconda. The whole point of Anaconda is that it's not so easy to install all this stuff, especially things like qt, so it comes with all those things for you.

Comment: If you don't like the full Anaconda distribution, try the Miniconda package manager instead (http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html). Sooner or later you will want multiple python environments and using the conda package and environment manager is very easy (once you got the concepts).

Answer (score 0):

While it is perfectly possible to install IPython (and all the necessary supporting modules) using a stock installation of Python on a Mac, I've found (and some will disagree with me) that the easiest way to go is to install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org). It creates an entirely separate hierarchy on your HD - `/opt/local` by default - and stores everything there, so it coexists peacefully with everything that's currently installed, and you don't have to worry about overwriting anything that the system relies on. Just add the appropriate directories to the front of your `$PATH`, and you're good to go.

The reason I prefer MacPorts over Homebrew is that it's centrally managed, frequently updated, and at least for my programming interests already have many of the modules I'm looking for as ports, so 9 times out of 10 I don't need to worry about installing with `pip`. It is very easy to update packages, and also keep multiple versions around if needed. The biggest advantage I've found, though, is the dependency management system, which has very rarely let me down, something I didn't see when I used Homebrew. If a dependency is needed for a certain port, it'll be installed automatically, and if it requires dependencies, those will be installed, etc.

Yes, you will use more storage space by installing MacPorts, Homebrew, or even the Python.org version of Python over using the included version. However, you will know that there are lots of people out there (it's all open-source) working to ensure that it stays working and incorporates the latest fixes and upgrades. You can still use `pip` and/or build your own packages using `setup.py` if you prefer, and those modules should work happily with the `port`-installed ones. Finally, with the cheapness of storage nowadays, sparing a few extra GB shouldn't be too hard (YMMV when it comes to final installed size...).

As far as [getting going](http://www.macports.org/install.php) is concerned, you'll need XCode and the XCode command-line tools to begin with (but those would be necessary if you wanted to build any non-pure-Python modules yourself with the system Python), a platform-appropriate `.pkg` installer file, and some spare time. Once everything is set up, simply run

```
sudo port install py27-ipython
```

and all the dependencies will be installed automagically for you.

Not everyone likes MacPorts, and I've run into plenty of people that swear by Homebrew. It didn't work that well for me when I first tried it a couple years back, and MacPorts has stayed current and very useful for me, which is why I recommend it. Homebrew may be loads better than it used to be, and if you have the time, inclination, and storage space you may want to try both, just to see how you like them.

Good luck with everything!

Comment: Very good advice, thank you Matt. I am inclined to try a raw install just to satisfy my hacker side. I suspect that Anaconda and Enthought will install a Framework in /Library/Frameworks, so they won't "pollute" my /usr directory. I have the IPython  download and am reading its install scripts. They seem to expect python to be in /usr/bin/env which seems weird. I will give it a go but have MacPorts and Enthought as plans B.

Comment: I am embarrassed to say I found an answer in a StackOverflow thread that I had overlooked: 

sudo /usr/bin/easy_install-2.6 python

Simple as that, although I will probably still have to manually get things like pandas, SciPy, etc. Onward!

Comment: Anaconda actually can install in whatever directory you point it to: every binary package in the Anaconda repo is painstakingly built to be relocatable. This means that you can create well-isolated "environments" with its conda packaging tool, and try out different versions of various packages.  Also, /usr/bin/env is not a location, but rather a tool to allow modification of environment parameters before launching a program (e.g. python).

Comment: @MattDMo, this will add another "apparently superfluous python installation" that was meant to not be installed in the first place in the question. (to not mention the very big xcode)

Comment: @flebool yes, I addressed that in my answer. The reason I answered the way I did is because historically there have been issues with the system Python on OS X not necessarily including all modules or being the most up-to-date version. I have not upgraded to Mavericks, so I don't know what version is current, but I have found that many people do much better by installing another version of Python beside the system one, whether it be Anaconda, Enthought, Python.org, MacPorts, Homebrew, or what have you.

Comment: Anaconda installs everything into `~/anaconda`. None of your existing directories are changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on my comment earlier, updating a suggestion at [How to install iPython on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437402/how-to-install-ipython-on-snow-leopard), my solution was to execute

sudo /usr/bin/easy_install-2.7 readline ipython

This results in an ipython installation that handles up/down-arrow history correctly.